# Recursively compute the number of nodes in a circular linked list given only head pointer

Tags: c++, recursion, circular-list

I'm writing this function as part of homework.  Wouldn't be such a big deal if there were a tail pointer included and most of the code was provided by my instructor and included in an object file, so I don't have the implementation to include.  Anyway, for some reason the base case in my function never gets reached.  Can anyone tell me why this keeps looping?

```
#include "clist.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int     data;
    node*   next;
};

//Iteratively compute and return the number of nodes in the circular linked list
int count(node* head)
{
    int nodeTotal = 1;
    node* temp = head;
    while(temp->next != head)
    {
        nodeTotal++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return nodeTotal;
}


//Recursively compute and return the number of nodes in the circular linked list
int countR(node* head)
{
    node* temp = head;
    if(temp->next == head)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + countR(temp->next);
}


//Iteratively compute and return the sum of the ints contained in the circular linked list
int sum(node* head)
{
    int valuesTotal = 2;
    node* temp = head;
    while(temp->next != head)
    {
        valuesTotal += temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return valuesTotal;
}

int main()
{
    node* head{nullptr};

    /* Builds a circular linked list with a random number of nodes
    *containing randomly-chosen numbers.
    */
    build(head);

    display(head);  

    // PUT YOUR CODE HERE to call the functions assigned,
    // and print out the results. For example,
    //
    //    cout << "iterative sum: " << sum(head) << endl;
    //
    // The code for your functions should be in clist.cpp.
    cout << "\nIterative node count: " << count(head) << endl;
    cout << "Iterative sum: " << sum(head) << endl;
    cout << "Recursive node count: " << countR(head) << endl;

    // When called the 2nd time, this also prints the total
    // of the numbers in the nodes.
    display(head);




    int     nNodesFreed{0};
    node*   n{head};
    node*   temp;

    while( n != head || ! nNodesFreed) {
        temp = n->next;
        delete n;
        n = temp;
        nNodesFreed++;

        }
    cout << "# nodes freed: " << nNodesFreed << endl;

    //destroy(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your bug should be child's play to find and with a relatively short list and stepping a few times with the debugger that came with your development environment.

Comment: If the recursion never stops, then of course it will "seg fault" due to stack overflow.  So what are you really asking?

Comment: What I'm wondering is why my stopping condition isn't working

Comment: @kbousman We need a [mcve], not code snippets.

Comment: @kbousman -- *What I'm wondering is why my stopping condition isn't working* -- If this is a homework problem, then that is included in your programming assignment -- learning how to debug your own programs.  Writing a program, seeing that it doesn't work, and then  have someone on SO debug the program -- it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- I understand that this is part of the assignment, and I wouldn't be posting on here if I hadn't already tried debugging and been at my wit's end.  So if you're just going to criticize me for asking for help, don't post anything to my question.

Comment: @kbousman So what have you observed while debugging?  When you wrote the program, you had a plan.  The program doesn't follow your plan.  You then single step through the program to see where it diverges from your plan.  You failed to even mention where your program starts to get away from what you expected.  So where does the program diverge from what you expected?

Comment: Post a transcript of your latest debugging session.

Comment: Also, what is `clist.h`?  That is part of this program, but it is missing.

Comment: I'm specifically wanting it to stop once temp->next == head, meaning it has gone all the way around the list.  Stepping through the debugger, I can see that it just keeps going through the list instead of stopping when temp->next == head and I'm wondering why.  I'm sure it's something small, but I've tried changing things up as much as I can to still obtain the results I need, but nothing seems to work.  I was hoping that another set of eyes on my code might help me see the problem.

Comment: @kbousman Unless `clist` has this, the code you posted does not maintain the actual head pointer in all of that recursion, thus your comparisons won't seem to work.  Also, what is the prototype of that `build` function?  It better be `build(node *&)` else I don't see how any of this code would work.

Comment: The build function was included with the program assignment and was written by my instructor, I don't have access to that implementation.  The code maintaining the actual head pointer has to be my issue.  I just have to figure that out now.  Thanks so much everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

Your stopping condition isn't working because each time you make a recursive call, you start with a new `head` pointer. So, let's say you start with a linked list like this:
[image]

On the first call, you pass `A` (well, the address of A), and it checks whether A == B. It doesn't, so it does a recursive call passing B. On that call, it checks whether B == C. That fails, so it does a recursive call passing C. That checks whether C == D. That fails, so it checks whether D == E. That fails, so it checks whether E == A. That fails, so it checks whether A == B. That still fails, so it continues...

And round and round it goes. Where it stops, nobody knows!

Comment: Thanks Jerry, this helps a lot!!